# How to enable a background thread to draw to NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-interface, cocoa, appkit

What is the best way to make **NSView** **drawRect:** render content that is drawn and updated by a background thread continuously?

1. Background thread updates backing store & flags view for update
2. macOS calls drawRect: to render backing store to screen

The background thread is running permanently.

Up until SDK 10.13 it was possible to have the background thread **lockFocus** / **unlockFocus** on NSView, which very efficiently populated the view's backing store. Rendering that backing store to screen in drawRect: was a snap.

With SDK 10.14 this no longer works (view remains black).

While it's possible to use a bitmap as a backing store, I'd prefer to avoid dealing with screen resolution and other specifics. I hope there's a more transparent and lean way (layers?)

Comment: Hey, do you already have an answer to that question?

Comment: @return-true A solution is to use NSView's **bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:** to create a resolution agnostic backing store. **[NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep: backingStore]** then gives the background thread a graphics context to paint on it. NSView **drawRect:** then draws the backingStore with **drawInRect:...**